# How can I move all files and directories from disk to the folder on this disk?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I have disk D with the files and directories. I want to move all files and directories *including the root* of disk D to the new folder saving the tree.

1. For example, I have file `D:\1.txt`. I want to move it to `D:\new_folder\1.txt`
2. The second example. I have file `D:\1\1\1.txt`. I want to move it to `D:\new_folder\1\1\1.txt`

As you can see, I want to move all contents of disk D to the folder  `D:\new_folder\`.

I tried robocopy, but it can't move from root of disk.

Comment: What have you tried ? pls share the code. Thats seems not an issue at all . Get-childitem -recurse along with move-item should do that

Answer (score 2):

This will copy all files and folders and preserve the folder structure:

```
$sourcePath = "D:\"
$destPath = "D:\new_folder\"

Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -Replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)
    if (!(Test-Path $destDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply using the [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) command?

```cmd
robocopy "D:\." "D:\new_folder" /E /MOVE /XD "D:\new_folder"
```

Note that you cannot specify the root `"D:\"`, because the backslash escapes the closing quotation mark. To work around that, specify either `"D:\."` or `"D:\\"`, which actually point to `D:\` both.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider to accept the answer that helped you most. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) why this is important! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not tested:

```
for /d %%# in (D:\*) do (
  xcopy "%%#" "D:\new_folder\%%~nx#" /i
)

for %%# in (D:\*) do (
  copy /Y "%%#" "D:\new_folder\"
)
```

Again not tested (with powershell):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\*" | ForEach-Object {if((Get-Item $_) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){Copy-Item "$_.FullName" "D:\new_folder" -recurse } else {Copy-Item "$_.FullName" "D:\new_folder"}}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can we do it by powershell?